# Watir webdriver - Unable to flash on a heading with class attribute

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I am trying to flash the text contained within the h2 tag. However, I am unable to do so when the h2 tag has the class attribute.

I am able to retrieve the text contained within the h2 tag but I do not seem to be able to flash the text. Please help.

Source code:

```
<div class="nextJump12 margin-bottom">
  <h2 class="white-gradient-bg border round-border">Next to jump</h2>
```

Watir-webdriver code:

```
@browser.div(:class => "nextJump12 margin-bottom").flash
@nexttojump = @browser.div(:class => "nextJump12 margin-bottom")
puts @nexttojump.h2.text
```

Comment: What do you mean by unable to flash? There are no error messages, but you do not see anything flashing?

Comment: Yes Zeljko. There are no error messages and yet, I do not observe anything flashing.

Comment: I think `flash` just changes the background of the element (to yellow or red), so if the background is already set to that color, you might not see anything.

Comment: Thank you, Zeljko - The background is in green or white. And the flash is by default in RED. Any other suggestions you can provide?

Answer (score 0):

As Željko mentioned, [`flash`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Element#flash-instance_method) just changes the background-color of the element being flashed.

In html, element's inherit styles of their parents/ancestors. However, an element can override its parent's styles by specifying its own style (class or inline).

For example, say your element was:

```
<div style="background-color:blue;">
  <h2>Next to jump</h2>
</div>
```

Then the h2 would inherit the div element's background-colour - ie would be displayed with a blue background.

Now let's say the h2 specifies its own background-colour:

```
<div style="background-color:blue;">
  <h2 style="background-color:green;">Next to jump</h2>
</div>
```

In the browser, you would only see a green background, not a blue background, around the h2. This is because the h2's styles take precedence over the styles inherited from the div.

This means that when you do:

```
browser.div.flash
```

You will see no change. The div's background would change between red and blue, but ultimately the h2's style would always override it.

Therefore you should try to flash the lowest elements in the DOM, in this case the h2. This way, regardless of what styles the h2 inherits or defines for itself, flash style change will take the highest precedence.

```
browser.div.h2.flash
```

So in your code, I would suggest trying:

```
browser.div(:class => "nextJump12 margin-bottom").h2.flash
```

Comment: Hello Justin,thanks for your reply. I tried to modify my code as suggested by you. However, it did not work.

Comment: I am not sure what else it could be. I would suggest that you try creating a page that reproduces the problem and that can be shared with us.